# ANT: Replace String in file with Filename itself

Tags: regex, ant, schema, replace

I have a situation where I need to scan through a large number of .xsd files, and replace an instance of a string with another string based on the file name of the current schema being examined.

For example:
I wish to replace the string: 'DataSet' in file1.xsd with the string 'file1DataSet'
I wish to replace the string: 'DataSet' in file2.xsd with the string 'file2DataSet'
and so on until all schemas have been modified.

I would like to know if there is anyway to do this without using the ant-contrib for loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the [<replace>](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replace.html) task if you have a generally good idea how many schemas you have. The [<replaceRegex>](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replaceregexp.html) might be able to do it without looping.

Ant isn't really a programming language where you can loop. If you can do everything in one pass, that's great, but once you start really manipulating files, Ant runs into limitations.

Comment: yes, I ended up caving around November 25th or so and used ant-contribs with a foreach target loop pointing to a pathconvert with a chainedmapper to extract the filename and a simple <replace file="${filelocation}" token="NewDataSet" value="${file.name}Type"/> statement.